# Pandas: find if a column name exists in excel sheet?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Using pandas:
I am reading 1 excel sheet & gathering data from it, to then create a new excel document.

The code I have only works if the user chooses an excel sheet that has the exact, specific string name for the column. I need to be able to check if the column name exists in the excel sheet. What I have now:

```
db = pandas.read_excel(full_path_with_file_name, sheetname=sheet_name)
list_values = db['column_name'].values
```

I grab that list of values and use it with xlsxwriter.

I would like to first check that the column EXISTS in excel before I gather the values from that column. If the column does not exist, I would just like to simply assign "unknown" as the value for the new xlsx.

I've tried various forms of:

```
if db['column_names']:
     list_values = db['column_name'].values
else:
     list_values = # just 'unknown' or 'not found'
```

Or some such version of that.

How to properly check that an excel column name exists?

Comment: Hey! May be use   if 'column name' in df.columns:

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to test a spreadsheet without opening it. Try this:

```
xls = pd.read_excel('test.xls', sheet_name="Sheet1")
df = pd.DataFrame({'COL0': np.nan*5}, np.arange(5))

columnsToSeek = ['COL2', 'COL3']

for col in columnsToSeek:
    if col in xls.columns:
        df[col] = xls[col]
    else:
        df[col] = 'UNKNOWN'
    
df

    COL0    COL2    COL3
0   NaN     cc      UNKNOWN
1   NaN     dd      UNKNOWN
2   NaN     NaN     UNKNOWN
3   NaN     NaN     UNKNOWN
4   NaN     NaN     UNKNOWN
```